# ASP.NET MVC app connects to Azure SQL Server db using server explorer, but gets "A network-related or instance-specific error" when locally hosted

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio

I have two ASP.NET MVC applications that connect to the same Azure SQL Server database. I've used both for a long time.

I recently reinstalled my local machine and got the files for both applications from TFS. One of them works with the database just fine. The other one can connect to the database using Visual Studio's Server Explorer using the EF connection string, but when I try to run it locally I get error 26:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I have checked my local IP is allowed through the Azure firewall. Any ideas why the second application won't run locally? A port issue or a cached file?

Thanks

Comment: Have you confirmed that your connection strings in the two separate apps are identical, and that when you're initializing your EF context, that the connection string is what you think it is?

Comment: Please check the connection string like Rob said.

Comment: My local code is a clean build of my latest code version on Azure DevOps. It was working before I reinstalled and updated my OS on my local machine. Nothing should have changed in the connection string. I have visually confirmed that and the Server Explorer in VS can connect using my entity connection string.

Answer (score 0):

My app is a small test application and I only used it locally so I never implemented the Owin Identity that was included in the generated project.

I had updated Visual Studio when I updated to Windows 10. Perhaps that made the Owin Identity mandatory. When I added a connection string for the identity system the app worked without issue again.

So it was an issue with the connection string, just not the EF connection string.